# Invalid identifier when trying to create a table with SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, create-table

I am trying to create a table and I get an invalid identifier error. What does this mean? I've looked over the code over and over. All of my other statements run perfectly. Can't figure out what the issue is with this.

Here is the statement that returns the error:

```
/* Create Transaction Table */
31 CREATE TABLE TRANSACTION(TxNbr INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
32                        TxCode CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
33                        AccountNbr INTEGER NOT NULL,
34                        Amount DECIMAL(13,2) NOT NULL,
35                         Date DATE,
36                         Time TIME,
37                         RefNbr VARCHAR(3),
38                         FOREIGN KEY(AccountNbr) REFERENCES ACCOUNT (AccountNbr) ON DELETE SET NULL,
39                         FOREIGN KEY(TxCode) REFERENCES TX_TYPE (TxCode) ON DELETE SET NULL
40                         );
```

Here is the error:

```
Error starting at line : 31 in command -
Error report -
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Short (non-CLOB) strings should be `VARCHAR2`, not `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`.

Comment: You really should give some thought to a good, rigorously enforced, naming standard.  If you did, that would avoid the problem of trying to use reserved words (like DATE) as an object name.  All of my column names are in the format <adjective>_<noun>.  And in the oracle world, (as opposed to MSSQL), the standard practice is to use underscores instead of mixed case.  Oracle ignores mixed case names unless you force it by encloseing them in double-quotes, and then that forces YOU to ALWAYS enclose them.  Just. Don't. Do. It.

Comment: @EdStevens thanks for the tops. I'll looking into the naming standard and start practicing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your code (not considering the foreign key constraints, that we cannot validate without actually knowing the structure of the related tables)

- `DATE` is a reserved word in Oracle (that's a datatype), so it can't be used for a column name, unless you surround it with double quotes - but if you do so, then you need to quote the column everytime you access it. I would suggest just using a column name that does not conflict with a language keyword.
- There is no `TIME`  datatype in Oracle; the `DATE` datatype  actually stores the date *and* time - which is generally better than separating the date and time portion in two different columns anyway anyway, since it makes date arithmetics easier. I would recommend just removing that column.

Consider:

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSACTION(
    TxNbr INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    TxCode CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    AccountNbr INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Amount DECIMAL(13,2) NOT NULL,
    TxDate DATE,
    RefNbr VARCHAR(3)
    FOREIGN KEY(AccountNbr) REFERENCES ACCOUNT (AccountNbr) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(TxCode) REFERENCES TX_TYPE (TxCode) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

Comment: And REFNBR should be VARCHAR2